# convert const values to API calls in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, flask

The following sample data will be coming from backend API call. The backend is flask and the API is already in place at the backend.

```
const rows = [
  {
    name: "XYZ",
    age: "12",
    email: "xyz@gmail.com"

  },
  {
    name: "David",
    age: "13",
    email: "David@gmail.com"

  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    age: "12",
    email: "abc@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

How can I integrate the backend API with React? I'm new to react, so I don't know how should I proceed.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you saying this `rows` value is something your backend API is providing? Are you asking how to make a request to the API? Please clarify.

Comment: @drew-reese sorry, I'll update the question. Yes, the rows value will be provided by the backend API from flask. I want to know how to make the request to that API using react.

Comment: https://react-query.tanstack.com/ is a pretty nice lib for wrapping REST APIs for React

Answer (score 1):

In React you'll have to use two hooks - `useState` and `useEffect`. The first one will help you keep the data so you can use it and the second one will help you getting it.

```js
function Component() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('your endpoint here').then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        return res.json();
      } else {
        // handle error
      }
    }).then(data => {
      setData(data);
    }).catch(err => {
      // handle error
    })
  }, []);

  if (data !== null) {
    return <p>Data is here {data.length}</p>;
  }

  return <p>Loading the data</p>;
}
```

And just to clarify that we need to use `useEffect` so we fire the request only once when the component is mounted. This is the effect of using `[]` for the dependencies' list as a second argument to the hook.

Comment: can we do it using `axios`?

Comment: Yes, but I personally prefer the native APIs. Fetch has pretty good support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API If you don't have to deal with IE you could safely use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios for sending api requests.

```
const [state,setState] = useState()

useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get(url)
     .then(res=>setState(res.data))
     .catch(err=>console.log(err))
},[])
```

Comment: This is incomplete. If you throw that in your component, it will fire requests on every re-render.